# Laravel , como ejecutar a un seeder diferente al DataBaseSeeder.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando crear un Seeder llamado users para poder modular para cada tabla distinta los seeds y tener mejor ordenado el proyecto. El problema es que cuando uso el comando:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Únicamente ejectuta el "DatabaseSeeder.php" aunque haya creado otro.

He probado a crearlo manualmente y usando la consola con el comando:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTable
```

El código que tengo en seed "UserTable" es:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    //Array users test
    private $users= array(
            array(  'name' => 'albert',
                    'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
                    'password' => '1234',
                    'role' => 1),
            array(  'name' => 'test',
                    'email' => 'test2@cima-webs.com',
                    'password' => 'test',
                    'role' => 2),
            array(  'name' => 'test2',
                    'email' => 'test3@cima-webs.com',
                    'password' => 'test2',
                    'role' => 2),
            array(  'name' => 'test3',
                    'email' => 'test4@cima-webs.com',
                    'password' => 'test3',
                    'role' => 2),
    );

    //contador de filas creadas
    private $rows = 0;
    public function userSeed() {
         //
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->users);$i++){

                //$this->command->info($this->users[$i].' Users cargados!');
                $this->command->info($this->users[$i]['email']);
                $this->command->info($this->users[$i]['password']);
                $user_seed = new User();            
                $user_seed->name = $this->users[$i]['name'];
                $user_seed->email = $this->users[$i]['email'];
                $user_seed->password = bcrypt($this->users[$i]['password']);
                $user_seed->role = $this->users[$i]['role'];
                $user_seed->save();
                $this->rows++;
        }
    }
    //function run
    public function run()
    {
            self::userSeed();
            $this->command->info($this->rows.' :Users cargados!');


    }
}
```

Si el código lo tengo en "DatabaSeeder.php" funciona perfectamente.

¿Podríais arrojarme algo de luz?

Gracias de antemano!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding#running-seeders) aclara este punto muy claramente , debe regenerar el `autoload` antes con el comando `composer dump-autoload`, luego ya podrá ejecutar el primer comando de su pregunta, además hay más opciones para ejecutar un `seeder` especifico puede hacerlo con el comando

```
php artisan db:seed --class=NombreDelSeeder
```

Para su ejemplo debería ser

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTable
```

O Simplemente.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! voy a probar esto y confirmo que funciona. Había visto el comando pero no lo había probado, por algún motivo en proyectos anteriores me funciona.